# How to remove default padding for separator for List in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have created List in SwiftUI, but it has extra padding for divider (separator), I want to reduce that leading padding and make same padding for trailing and leading.

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView() {
        List(modelData) { weather in
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: weather.image)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 10, alignment: .leading)
                Text("\(weather.temp)º")
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 10, alignment: .leading)
                VStack {
                    Text(weather.city)
                }
            }.font(.title)

        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("World Weather"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The padding comes from the minimum List row height. You can remove it by setting

```
        List(modelData) { weather in
        ...
        }
        .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
```